# A step-by-step unhiding "tutorial mode" for equations

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, answers, spoilers

One [very nice MathJax example](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-steps.html) shows means to only show parts of a formula (e.g. as hints) and unveil them one by one (see $\ref{screenshot}$ below). I think a similar feature (not restricted to equations, also including text), as extension to the `>!` spoiler tag, e.g.

```
First of all, make sure $a_n$ converges for $n\to\infty$.
>!   Here are a few hints:                     # shown on hover
>!2! In order to do so, do ...                 # shown after 2nd click
>!2! In your example this would be ...         # also shown after 2nd click
>!3!   The partial result should be:           # shown after 3rd click
>!1! Then, take a look at $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ ...  # shown after 1st click

>!1! This is another spoiler block             # shown after 1st click *here*
```

(where the spoilers were unveiled in numerical order by clicking on the spoiler block) would help in posting instructive answers (teaching how to fish etc). To be more precise, this would be how it works:

- In each *contiguous* spoiler block, lines starting with `>!#!` (with `#` being a number) will only be shown after `#` clicks into that block and do not necessarily have to be sequential
- Multiple lines can have the same number `#` in order to unveil larger blocks at once
- Separate spoiler blocks have separate click-counters (or not, I'm not sure about this one)
- In order to prevent people from turning this into a PowerPoint thing, only single digit `#` are permitted and there is no way to re-hide things
- The print version of the site will already show all spoilers

$\tag{screenshot}\label{screenshot}$
[image: Screenshot from MathJax example]

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good point, though it should not be restricted to that

Comment: You are right. So probably the ([meta-tag:mathjax]) tag can be (or perhaps should be) removed. In any case, I leave it up to you as the OP.

Comment: It's fine, the primary context where this would be is probably equations - though partially unveiled aligned multiline equations would probably require some deeper MathJax plumbing...

Comment: Does something like this work: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524082/when-does-the-triangle-have-the-smallest-area/524095#524095  ?

Comment: @zyx That's the way it currently has to be done - one could add something like `spoiler #2` before it, but one still has to hover over each spoiler box (or select the text) to reveal it; a clickable box with a fixed unveiling order would be neater...

Comment: Here is the spectrum of what it looks like now, with: no space between blocks
( http://math.stackexchange.com/a/392956/14120 ) ;

empty lines between blocks
( http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9455/14120 ) ;

text between blocks
( http://math.stackexchange.com/a/524095/14120 ) .